# Android - ListView duplicate events

Tags: android, listview, onscroll

In my app I have a ListView backed by ArrayAdapter. In it I'm detecting events in OnScrollListener#onScroll method to find end of the list. I noticed that on the phone (MyTouch) both track-ball and gesture/touch scrolling will trigger the event twice. On the emulator I get the same behavior with a scrolling wheel and click-and-drug scrolling. However in emulator if I use down-arrow button to scroll the event is fired only once.

Here's the code:

```
this.view.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int first, 
                                final int visible, final int total) {
        // detect if last item is visible
        if (visible < total && (first + visible == total)) {
            Log.d("OnScrollListener - end of list", "fvi: " + 
               first + ", vic: " + visible + ", tic: " + total);
            // this line gets called twice
            onLastListItemDisplayed(total, visible);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I suppress or handle this behavior? I need just a single event and trying not to revert to silly hacks such as boolean field.

As far as I can tell - both events have identical stacktrace

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 116 in SearchResultsView$4)) 
 SearchResultsView$4.onScroll(AbsListView, int, int, int) line: 116 
 ListView(AbsListView).invokeOnItemScrollListener() line: 655 
 ListView.arrowScrollImpl(int) line: 2256 
 ListView.arrowScroll(int) line: 2172 
 ListView.commonKey(int, int, KeyEvent) line: 1977 
 ListView.onKeyMultiple(int, int, KeyEvent) line: 1929 
 KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent$Callback) line: 899 
 ListView(View).dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 3647 
 ListView(ViewGroup).dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 744 
 ListView.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 1909 
 FrameLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 746 
 LinearLayout(ViewGroup).dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 746 
 PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 746 
 PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 1708 
 PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 1197 
 SearchResultsView(Activity).dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 1967 
 PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent) line: 1684 
 ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(KeyEvent, boolean) line: 2329 
 ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(int, boolean) line: 2299 
 ViewRoot.handleMessage(Message) line: 1621 
 ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
 Looper.loop() line: 123 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4203 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 791 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 549 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

P.S. [Bug is created](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4239)

P.P.S. And closed with very useful reply `The trackball and the touch screen send several motion events very rapidly. This behavior is expected.`

Comment: I remember running across this once too. Never did find a solution. Good luck.

Comment: I posted a bug at Android bug-tracking site, see if they can at least comment on that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since good people of Google are saying that this is `as intended` here's an ugly brutal way of dealing with this problem that works for me. Basically the assumption here is that as events are issued I compare last saved first item index with one that is passed in the `onScroll` call. I will only process event if these do not match:

```
    this.view.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        private int lastSavedFirst = -1;
        @Override
        public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int first, final int visible, final int total) {
            // detect if last item is visible
            if (visible < total && (first + visible == total)) {
                // only process first event
                if (first != lastSavedFirst) {
                    lastSavedFirst = first;
                    Log.d("OnScrollListener - end of list", "fvi: " + first + ", vic: " + visible + ", tic: "
                            + total);
                    onLastListItemDisplayed(total, visible);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
            // Log.d("OnScrollListener", "state: " + scrollState);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got also this problem with multiple events firing of while I was scrolling through the ListView. I've intended to load more ListItems that moment when I was passing a treshold value. However, this always resulted in multiple called AsyncTasks which populated my ListView faster than wanted.

I've found a good solution in [this blogpost](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/). It basically includes a check for a boolean, although you dislike this solution. I find it also some kind of hacky but I did not came up with another solution though.